# Matching Two Strings then copy paste Data

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have been trying to make a function where it matches 2 separate strings with two column then copy corresponding columns data and paste into separate sheet.

I am stuck on that thing **how to make 2 matches** like `For Each cell In myDataRng & myDataRng2`.

your help will be appreciated

```
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim myDataRng, myDataRng2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim destRow As Range
    Dim FindValue As String
    Dim FindValue2 As String
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")  'source sheet
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'destination sheet
    
    FindValue = wsDest.Range("A2").Value
    FindValue2 = wsDest.Range("B2").Value
    
    Set myDataRng = wsSrc.Range("F2:F" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set myDataRng2 = wsSrc.Range("A2:A" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set destRow = wsDest.Rows(2)  'first destination row
    
    For Each cell In myDataRng
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, FindValue) > 0 Then
        
            With cell.EntireRow 'the whole matching row
                destRow.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(2).Value
                destRow.Cells(6).Value = .Cells(3).Value
                destRow.Cells(7).Value = .Cells(4).Value
                destRow.Cells(8).Value = .Cells(5).Value
            End With
            
            Set destRow = destRow.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row
            
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Other Condition

```
Sub find()

Dim foundRng As Range
Dim mValue As String

Set shData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set shSummary = Worksheets("Sheet2")

mValue = shSummary.Range("C2")

    Set foundRng = shData.Range("G1:Z1").find(mValue)
    'If matches then copy macthed Column and paste into Sheet2 Col"I" (as above code psting the data into Sheet2)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

```
If Instr(1, cell.Offset(,-5).Value, FindValue2) > 0 Then
```

```
If InStr(1, wsSrc.Range("A" & cell.Row), FindValue2) > 0 Then
```

and others.

Comment: After adding second match now i have been receiving an error on the workbook `“We found a problem with some content in ‘filename.xlsx’. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.` then i add in immediate window this and press enter and this `"? application.StartupPath" ` appear ` `expected : line number or label or statement or end of statement` why this is happening @BigBen

Comment: Without your workbook, it's going to be hard to know exactly. I don't see anything in your code that should cause issues.

Comment: Oh my bad it contains necessary details cannot share it openly.

Comment: Not your bad then. From what I can see, you're only copying values from the source sheet to the destination sheet. That's straightforward. Adding a second `InStr` check shouldn't corrupt a file. So, unsure what the issue is. Is your code doing anything else besides the snippet above?

Comment: I have fixed the problem the issue was other code which has been updated. I need one more favor that is to add third condition in above code.
condition is to match the header values with C2 value if matches then copy data from the matched column and paste like as above code is pasting the data. I have updated the other code which i create just for an example to show what i am trying to achieve  @BigBen

Comment: You would first test if the `Find` succeeded. `If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then`. I'm not sure then what you want to copy.

Comment: there are `20 headers in Sheet1` and in `Sheet2 Range(C2)` i have added `Data validation` for these 20 headers. i will select any header value from C2 and will match `Sheet1 Range(G1:Z1) if C2 header is found then copy active column. For example I selected in `Sheet2 Range(C2)` `JOHN` then code will find in Headers if `JOHN` found then copy the Column which header is `JOHN`

Comment: If you don't want to copy the header `JOHN`, then use `foundRng.Offset(1).Resize(...)` to refer to the cells below. If you know which rows you want to copy, you can use something like `shData.Rows("2:20").Columns(foundRng.Column)` to refer to the range to copy.

Comment: How to copy the whole column `foundRng.Offset(1).Copy` i would appreciated the help. and where to use the `shData.Rows("2:20").Columns(foundRng.Column)` this

Comment: `shData.Rows("2:20").Columns(foundRng.Column).Copy`. You might have to make the rows `2:20` dynamic.

Comment: Last thing please how to make it Dynamic i have searched but could not find `shData.Rows("2:5").Columns(foundRng.Column).Copy` @BigBen

Comment: `With shData`, `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, foundRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row`, `.Rows("2:" & lastRow).Columns(foundRng.Column).Copy`, `End With`.

Answer (score 0):

I like using rows for loops like this because it makes it very easy to read the code and understand what is happening. By breaking the search range into a series of rows, everything becomes simple to write and read.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim myDataRng, myDataRng2 As Range
    Dim rRow As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim destRow As Range
    Dim FindValue As String
    Dim FindValue2 As String
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")  'source sheet
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'destination sheet
    
    FindValue = wsDest.Range("A2").Value
    FindValue2 = wsDest.Range("B2").Value
    
    Set myDataRng = wsSrc.Range("F2:F" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
    'Set myDataRng2 = wsSrc.Range("A2:A" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set destRow = wsDest.Rows(2)  'first destination row
    
    For Each rRow In myDataRng.Rows.EntireRow
        If InStr(1, rRow.Columns("F").Value, FindValue) > 0 _
        And InStr(1, rRow.Columns("A").Value, FindValue2) > 0 Then
        
            With rRow.EntireRow 'the whole matching row
                destRow.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(2).Value
                destRow.Cells(6).Value = .Cells(3).Value
                destRow.Cells(7).Value = .Cells(4).Value
                destRow.Cells(8).Value = .Cells(5).Value
            End With
            
            Set destRow = destRow.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row
            
        End If
    Next rRow

End Sub
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")  'source sheet
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'destination sheet
    
    FindValue = wsDest.Range("A2").Value
    FindValue2 = wsDest.Range("B2").Value
    
    Set myDataRng = wsSrc.Range("F2:F" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
    'Set myDataRng2 = wsSrc.Range("A2:A" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set destRow = wsDest.Rows(2)  'first destination row
    
    For Each rRow In myDataRng.Rows
        If InStr(1, rRow.Columns("F").Value, FindValue) > 0 _
        And InStr(1, rRow.Columns("A").Value, FindValue2) > 0 Then
        
            With rRow.EntireRow 'the whole matching row
                destRow.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(2).Value
                destRow.Cells(6).Value = .Cells(3).Value
                destRow.Cells(7).Value = .Cells(4).Value
                destRow.Cells(8).Value = .Cells(5).Value
            End With
            
            Set destRow = destRow.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row
            
        End If
    Next rRow

End Sub
```